# How do i change the margin of a fluid container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

On the right side of the box, theres no margin.I get that its suppose to cover the entire horizontal width of the screen, but then why can we apply the margin on the left side of container?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:pink;padding:15%; margin:15%;">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
    <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Also I know there is class called container, but it jumps from a specific width to another width when i reduce the viewport, i was wondering if there a way to make sure it goes smoothly like container-fluid but with the added margins.

Comment: why add a `container` class at all? There is no need to add the `container` class if you don't want any of the specific BS5 mechanisms and stylings. It works fine when you not use that class.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with bootstrap-5 and your code shows bootstrap-4?

Answer (score 0):

use the right syntax with **row** and **col**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container-fluid" >
<div class="row" style="background-color:pink;padding:15%; margin:15%;">
<div class="col">
<h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
  <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           
</div>
</div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this for spacing in bootstrap:

[Spacing, How it works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without bootstrap pure css

Create a wrapper div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Without Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:pink;padding:15%; margin:15%;">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
  <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Flex without container

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="d-flex p-5 m-5" style="background:pink;">

<h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
  <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           

  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Container with flex, center vertically and horizontally and a div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

<div class="TextOutput" style="background:pink; margin:15%;padding:15%;">
<h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
  <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>           
</div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```